# ImageMagick commercial equivalent for both OSX and Windows

Tags: windows, macos, installation, imagemagick

Is there a commercial product out there that can provide what ImageMagick "convert" function provides for both Windows and OSX?

I'm planning on a distributing a desktop app that requires "convert" functionality but the installations for ImageMagick for OSX is not trivial.  The dependancy on Ghostscript for vector graphics is also a barrier.

I was hoping to find a vendor that can provide the same functionality all in one package for both Windows and OSX and buy a distribution license from them.  I'm hoping this could give me a more robust experience for the user as far as the installation.  Any advise on this topic is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can tell, installing ImageMagick on Mac OSX is quite easy. You just have to install `MacPorts` (http://www.macports.org/install.php) and do a `sudo port install ImageMagick`

Greetings,

Jan

Comment: Thank you for your response. Macport although easy is more of a developer tool.  My users would then be require to first download xcode. Then download and install Macport. Run the command to install imagemagick and then wait for good hour or so before being able to use my application which depends on ImageMagick.  My preference would be either a dmg file with all the necessary files for ImageMagick or a commercial vendor application dmg that would make this a one click and quick install.